# What is an 'async_generator' & how is it different from a 'coroutine' in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, asynchronous, generator, python-asyncio, coroutine

I suspect this has something to do with the differences b/w `yield from` & `await`.
However, & aside from the new object's designation as an `async_generator`, I'm unclear about consequences regarding the differences between it and a `coroutine`.
(I'm not sure how else to ask the question other than the one I put in the title...)

```
import asyncio

async def async_generator_spits_out_letters():
    yield 'a'
    yield 'b'
    yield 'c'
    yield 'd'
    await asyncio.sleep(0)

async def coroutine_prints_messages():
    while True:
        print('hi')
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

def test_it():
    print(type(async_generator_spits_out_letters))
    print(type(coroutine_prints_messages))
    # This is how I choose to do newlines....it's easier for me to read. :[
    print(); print()

    print(type(async_generator_spits_out_letters()))
    print(type(coroutine_prints_messages()))
```

This gives:

```
<class 'async_generator'>
<class 'coroutine'>


<class 'function'>
<class 'function'>
```

I can't make heads or tails of this...

Comment: A generator `yield`s, a coroutine does not.

Comment: Is that the only difference b/w the two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In order for *an* `async_generator`*-producing function* to run in an eventloop, its output must be wrapped in a `coroutine.`

This is to prevent the `async_generator` from yielding values directly INTO the event-loop.

```
import asyncio

# This produces an async_generator
async def xrange(numbers):
    for i in range(numbers):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(0)

# This prevents an async_generator from yielding into the loop.
async def coroutine_wrapper(async_gen, args):
    try:
        print(tuple([i async for i in async_gen(args)]))
    except ValueError:
        print(tuple([(i, j) async for i, j in async_gen(args)]))
```

### Loops only like tasks & futures.

If a loop receives an integer or string or..anything not derived from a `future` from one of its tasks, it will break.

**Therefore `coroutines` must either:**

- produce `future`s (or subclasses of `future`,)
- OR NOT pass any values back into the loop.

## Here's main():

```
def main():
    print('BEGIN LOOP:')
    print()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    xrange_iterator_task = loop.create_task(coroutine_wrapper(xrange, 20))
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(xrange_iterator_task)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.stop()
    finally:
        loop.close()
    print()
    print('END LOOP')
    print(); print()
    print('type(xrange) == {}'.format(type(xrange)))
    print('type(xrange(20) == {}'.format(type(xrange(20))))
    print()
    print('type(coroutine_wrapper) == {}'.format(type(coroutine_wrapper)))
    print('type(coroutine_wrapper(xrange,20)) == {}'.format(type(coroutine_wrapper(xrange, 20))))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Here's the output:

```
BEGIN LOOP:

(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)

END LOOP


type(xrange) == <class 'function'>
type(xrange(20)) == <class 'async_generator'>

type(coroutine_wrapper) == <class 'function'>
type(coroutine_wrapper(xrange,20)) == <class 'coroutine'>
```